# How to run QuickTime-associated file from NSIS installer?

Tags: installation, executable, nsis, quicktime

We require users to have a copy of QTJava.zip in their jre/lib/ext folder so that we can play QuickTime files without adding to the classpath. QuickTime provides an installation process for this here: http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/QuickTime_for_Java:_A_Developer%27s_Notebook/Getting_Up_and_Running_with_QuickTime_for_Java (see the section labeled **Preflighting a QTJ Installation**) So basically we need to run a QT-associated file from within the installer - since QT will already be installed, it will just launch the movie player when the ".mov" file is run.

We have a selection dialog where the user selects his JRE, and we'd like to prompt the user to run this installer immediately after this step (assuming QTJava isn't there already; we do check for this). Assuming the ".mov" file resides in the base installer folder, what steps are involved in "running" this file? Nothing so far has worked, and listing each method we've tried would take up pages, so a fresh perspective would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you require users to have QTJava.zip to play the .mov? QuickTime can be installed on the system but JRE may not have QTJava.zip; other player capable of playing .mov file can be installed… What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: We use QTJava to play the files in our application, so the location needs to be present in the classpath. It doesn't matter to us what other apps the user has installed as we require QTJ to play QT files.

Comment: So want to play a .mov file in your application, is it right? Then this question has nothing to do with installers (you seem to have solved that part), and you should read *QTJava API documentation*.

Answer (score 1):

Running non .exe/.cmd/.bat files requires ExecShell. ExecShell is as close to "double-click in explorer" you are going to get.

But there is a problem here, .mov is a common extension and you don't know what the end user has set to open .mov files, it could be MPC, VLC, mplayer etc so just using ExecShell could fail.

It is probably better to try to locate QT and execute it directly:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Apple Computer, Inc.\Quicktime" "InstallDir"
ExecShell "" '"$0\QuicktimePlayer.exe"' '"$Instdir\MyFile.mov"'
```

Comment: I knew I'd have to call QuickTimePlayer.exe with the file as an arg - sorry I wasn't explicit about that. But the above method doesn't work for two reasons: The .mov file doesn't exist on disk for QT to execute (error -43), and the installer continues immediately. Since we need to know if the user actually installed QTJ, the process needs to act like ExecWait. Is there a way to copy this file to the disk (maybe in some temporary folder?) and then run with ExecWait? I tried this method using $PLUGINSDIR, but the folder wasn't created, so nothing could be copied there.

Comment: @wade Use InitPluginsDir before you copy to $pluginsdir.